# SQLite WinRT wrapper gives mismatch between the processor architecture in Windows phone 8.1 project

Tags: c#, windows, sqlite, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a WinJS project for Windows Phone 8.1. I added [SQLite-WinRT wrapper](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andy_wigley/2013/11/21/how-to-massively-improve-sqlite-performance-using-sqlwinrt/) in Windows Runtime Component. But, it gives error in **ARM** configuration but it doesn't gives any error in **x86** configuration. I need to run my project in real device so ARM onfiguration is must needed in that case. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

*Screenshot showing error with ARM configuration*

[image]

*Screenshot without error with x86 configuration*

[image]

**Error:**
`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "ARM" and the processor architecture, "x86", of the implementation file "C:\Users\Test\Desktop\AMTEK\Smart_WindowsPhone\packages\Sqlite-Winrt.3.8.7.1\lib\wpa81\SQLiteWinRT.dll" for "C:\Users\Test\Desktop\AMTEK\Smart_WindowsPhone\packages\Sqlite-Winrt.3.8.7.1\lib\wpa81\SQLiteWinRT.winmd". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and implementation file, or choose a winmd file with an implementation file that has a processor architecture which matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.   SmartflowRuntimes`

Answer (score 0):

For windows phone why arent you using
 `SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1 (SQLite.WP81, Version=3.9.2)` nuget package? 
WinRT is meant for desktop apps only. If you are creating Windows 8.1 app then you do need to add specific SQLite references in both.
1) `SQLite for Windows Runtime (Windows 8.1)` `SQLite.WinRT81, Version=3.10.2` in Windows 8.1
2) `SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1` `SQLite.WP81, Version=3.9.2` in windows phone 8.1
Also you would require to rebuild any **portable or reference project** that you might have added to the specific Debug configuration and then build your project to avoid any error.

Comment: Hi Jerin, Thanks for your answer. I have the same project on Windows app for PCs. And it works well there. I have to use the same wrapper in windows phone 8.1 app since I'm using the same sqlite-winrt metthods in windowsphone app as in windows app. I found that SQLite-WinRT wrapper supports in both windows apps and windows phone apps. http://sqlwinrt.codeplex.com/

Comment: It works well for PC as PC version is WinRT version and this project is specifically meant for that but not windows phone 8.1 version. This version Supports the Silverlight version of Windows Phone 8.1. [Discussion](http://sqlwinrt.codeplex.com/discussions/568083) and [Issue](http://sqlwinrt.codeplex.com/workitem/6) on this site proves that.

Comment: Hi Jerin, It is working in Windows phone 8.1 emulator. Not working in windows phone 8.1 real device since I need to change configuration to ARM and gives the error.

Comment: What about PCL files? whats their build configuration?

Comment: I didn't get you. Do you mean build configuration? Can you please see the above screenshots. I have the exact same build configuration shown in screenshots.

Comment: Yes I saw the screenshots. But it does happen that all referenced projects sometimes throw an error even when you build it by setting the global debug configuration. The solution that worked me was right clicking on these referenced projects->Properties->build->Configuration change to Release and Target Platform change to ARM. save it then right click and rebuild this project. Once you have done that for every referenced project now try to deploy it. If this still doesnt fix then could you share a sample app with this problem?

Comment: Hi Jerin, I followed the same as you suggested but no luck. I have create a test project with the same problem. It works well in windows phone 8.1 emulator with Build Configuration to x86 but gives the error in ARM when running in Windows Phone 8.1 device. Can you have a look on this sample app? https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B51hSmFg25s7cWxpNjhPNWtoa1U&usp=sharing Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105790/discussion-between-jerin-and-kishor-bikram-oli).